# Another class interacting with variables in main method

Tags: java, methods, scope, private, final

I have a main method which creates a `List<Long>`. I then have another class whose state is a `List<Long>` - the goal of this class is to take in the main method's `List<Long>` as its state and do manipulations to it without affecting the main method's `List<Long>`.

However the problem that I am facing is that this other class is impact **both** its state (its `private List<Long>`) **as well as** the `List<Long>` in the main method.

How do I adjust my code such that `setTesting(...)` is only able to influence the state of its class?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        final List<Long> mainlist = new ArrayList<Long>();
        mainlist.add((long) 1);
        mainlist.add((long) 2);
        mainlist.add((long) 3);


        Test testlist = new Test();
        testlist.setTesting(mainlist);

        System.out.println(testlist.getTesting());
        testlist.removal((long) 1);
        System.out.println(testlist.getTesting());



    }
}





public class Test {

    private List<Long> testing = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public Test() {
    }

    public void removal(Long remove) {
        this.testing.removeAll(Collections.singleton(remove));
    }

    public void setTesting(List<Long> list) {
        this.testing = list;
    }

    public List<Long> getTesting() {
        return this.testing;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `testing`  reference in your class is referring to the same list you created in main method, so making any change will change the main method list. If you want to create a new list using the  list passed in your `setTesting` method, then do something like this:

```
   public void setTesting(List<Long> list) {
        this.testing = new ArrayList<Long>(list);
    }
```

using the `new` keyword in `setTesting`, a new list will be created using the input list. Any change to this new list will not impact the original main method list.

Also you can remove the initialization of testing list from the class level, simply declare it:

```
private List<Long> testing;
```

Comment: You get the best answer because of the suggestion at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Make a defensive copy.

```
public void setTesting(List<Long> list) {
     this.testing = new ArrayList<Long>(list);
    }
```

The current problem is that your `Test` object and `main` method both refer to the same list. So, if anyone modifies the list other sees it to. The solution is just to have different copy for both of them.

A word of caution: the solution above will copy the same references in the new list too, though here it doesn't matter.

Comment: About your word of caution: But that doesn't matter in this case because class `Long` is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because there is only one `List<Long>`. In the `main` method you're passing it to `setTesting` in class `Test`, but there you're just storing a reference to the list that was created in `main`. Remember that in Java, variables are **references** to objects - they are not the objects themselves. If you use `=`, like you do in your `setTesting` method, you are only copying the reference to the list, you're not creating a copy of the list. If you want the `Test` object to have its own copy, you'll have to copy the list yourself:

```
public void setTesting(List<Long> list) {
    // Creates a copy of the list
    this.testing = new ArrayList<Long>(list);
}
```